# Can only the existence of the right and left derivatives imply continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

If $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \,$ is a function with $x_0 \in \overline{X}   \,\setminus \partial(\overline{X}) $ such that :

$$\exists \,\,\,\,f'_-(x_0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^-}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0},$$

$$\exists \,\,\,\,f'_+(x_0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^+}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$
 but with possibly $f'_-(x_0) \not= f'_+(x_0)$,  does this still imply continuity of $f$ ?

Comment: Have you tried showing that existence of the left derivative implies left continuity?  What about the right side?

Comment: I thought of doing that, but something seems strange, i have been thinking of a case in which i have a point $x_0 \in \text{int}(\overline{X})$ such that i can show left continuity and right continuity but nothing about continuity on the point $x_0$ itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that$$\lim_{x\to{x_0}^+}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$exists (in $\mathbb R$). Then\begin{align}\lim_{x\to{x_0}^+}f(x)&=f(x_0)+\lim_{x\to{x_0}^+}f(x)-f(x_0)\\&=f(x_0)+\lim_{x\to{x_0}^+}\left((x-x_0)\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\right)\\&=f(x_0)+\lim_{x\to{x_0}^+}(x-x_0)\lim_{x\to{x_0}^+}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\\&=f(x_0)+0\\&=f(x_0).\end{align}For the same reason, if$$\lim_{x\to{x_0}^-}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$exists (in $\mathbb R$), then $\lim_{x\to{x_0}^-}f(x)=f(x_0)$.

Comment: "In fact, just the existence of one of these limits will be enough."  Are you claiming that the existence of the right-sided derivative at $x_{0}$ implies $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$?

Comment: @fourierwho Yes. And I was wrong, of course. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @FelipeDilho If $x_0\notin X$, then it makes no sense to ask if $f$ is or not continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos true it is necessary that $x \in X$
for it to make any sense talking about continuity in $x_0$. But if i had something like$$f(x) =       \begin{cases}       3x \, , \text{  if}  \,\,\, x<x_0 \\       10x+1 \, ,\text{  if}  \,\,\, x=x_0 \\       -2x \, , \text{  if}  \,\,\, x>x_0       \end{cases}$$ it would have left and right derivatives well defined but it still is not continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: @FelipeDilho In your example, what is the value of $x_0$?

Comment: It's all right I already made another question and clarified my doubts thank you !

Comment: @FelipeDilho I'm glad I could help.